# Drag and drop in accordion group

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, drag-and-drop, accordion, bootstrap-accordion

I am an amateur in front-end development and hence need some guidance.

I have a project in which i am using a floating icons bar whose position I store in database and on refreshing or re login of page I use that saved position to show that bar.

Code:

```
ko.components.register("shortcut-strip", {
    viewModel: function (params) {
        var self = this;
        self.ribbonIcons = params.data;
        self.eleId = params.eleId;
        self.showShortcutStrip = params.showShortcutStrip;

        self.setWidth = ko.computed(function () {
            if(self.ribbonIcons().length){
                //var toggleBtnWidth = $("#sToggle").parents('li').outerWidth();
                var btnWidth = $(".shortcutIcons li").eq(0).outerWidth() || 26;
                return (btnWidth * self.ribbonIcons().length) + 'px';
            }
        });
        self.position = params.position;

        setTimeout(function () {
            var dm = document.getElementById(self.eleId);
            dm.addEventListener('dragstart', drag_start, false);
            document.body.addEventListener('dragover', drag_over, false);
            document.body.addEventListener('drop', drop, false);
        }, 100);

        function drag_start(event) {
            var style = window.getComputedStyle(event.target, null);
            event.dataTransfer.setData("text (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("left"), 10) - event.clientX) + ',' + (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("top"), 10) - event.clientY))";
        }

        function drag_over(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }

        function drop(event) {
            var offset = event.dataTransfer.getData("text").split(',');
            var dm = document.getElementById('dragme');
            dm.style.left = (event.clientX + parseInt(offset[0], 10)) + 'px';
            dm.style.top = (event.clientY + parseInt(offset[1], 10)) + 'px';
            savePositionMethod(dm.style.left, dm.style.top);
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    },
    template: '<div data-bind="attr:{id : eleId}, visible: showShortcutStrip, style: {left: position()[0], top: position()[1]}" draggable="true"><div class="shortcut-strip"><ul class="pull-left"><li> <span><img id="sToggle" style="padding: 5px 0px 4px 7px;" src="image.png"/> </span></li></ul> <ul class="shortcutIcons" data-bind="style:{width: setWidth()}"> <!-- ko foreach: ribbonIcons --> <li><img data-bind="attr :{src: Iconsrc, class: Class, title: title}, click: $root.performImageAction" /> </li> <!-- /ko --> </ul></div> </div>'
});
```

But what it does is that it makes all the anchor tags and links in the page as draggable and hence drop event is fired on all the elements.
How can  I solve this problem ? Please help.

And secondly I need to implement drag and drop in my accordion group as well whose code is as follows:

```
<div class="accordion-group" id="assignedAccordion">
    <!--  ko foreach : Data() -->
    <div class="accordion-default" id="documentScroll">
        <div class="panel-title bg-none" data-bind="css:{active : isCollapsed()}">
            <span class="toggle" data-bind="click: $root.toggleCollapse, css:{expand : isCollapsed(), collapsed: !isCollapsed()}")> </span>
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-bind="event: {contextmenu: $root.documentMenu, click: $root.getData}"></a>
            <input type="checkbox" class="assignedDocCheckbox" data-bind="checked: isChecked">
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-body" data-bind="style:{display : isCollapsed() ? 'block' : 'none'}">
            <!-- ko if: $data.documentData().length > 0 -->
                <ul data-bind="foreach: documentData()[0].pages">
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tool-tip" data-bind="event:{contextmenu: $root.pageMenu, click: $root.selectPage}, css:{'activePage' : $root.activePage() === $data}">
                            ${pageDispName} <span data-bind="text: displayName"></span>
                    </a></li>
                </ul>
            <!-- /ko-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```